# Error on using custom build task in Microsoft Build Framework

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, msbuild-buildengine

I have implemented a custom BuildTask and set the build engine in it.
But while executing the code, I am getting this exception

```
Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Task.set_BuildEngine(Microsoft
.Build.Framework.IBuildEngine)'.
```

What can be possible cause of this?

Answer (score 2):

You may be using two different versions of the Microsoft Build Framework (Microsoft.Build.Framework). Check the version numbers in the item properties to make sure they're not different (e.g. my issue - Version 4.0.0.0 and Version 14.0.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem started when I upgraded the build project to use Visual Studio 2015. The build task that was being tested was referencing the `Microsoft.Build.Framework` that was installed into the GAC (4.0.0.0.). I had to set the `HintPath` to use the `MSBuild 14` version of the `Microsoft.Build.Framework` on the assembly that was being tested as well as the test assembly and that fixed the problem.